# libpam-ldapd not looking for secondary groups

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ldap, pam

I'm migrating from **libpam-ldap** to **libpam-ldapd**. I'm having some trouble gathering the secondary groups from LDAP.

On **libpam-ldap**, I had this on the `/etc/ldap.conf` file:

```
nss_schema rfc2307bis
nss_base_passwd         ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es
nss_base_shadow         ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es
nss_base_group          ou=Groups,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es
nss_map_attribute       uniqueMember  member
```

The mapping is there because I'm using `groupOfNames` instead of `groupOfUniqueNames` LDAP class for groups, so the attribute naming the members is named `member` instead of `uniqueMember`.

Now, I want to do the same using **libpam-ldapd** but I can't get it to work. Here's the relevant part of my `/etc/nslcd.conf`:

```
base passwd         ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es
base shadow         ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es
base group          ou=Groups,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es
map group uniqueMember member
```

And this is the debug output from nslcd, when a user is authenticated:

```
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: connection from pid=12090 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byuid(4004)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uidNumber=4004))")
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.54.31/)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,10)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,10)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,10)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("uid=ubuntu,ou=Applications,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es","*****") (uri="ldap://172.16.54.31/")
nslcd: [8b4567] connected to LDAP server ldap://172.16.54.31/
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: connection from pid=15906 uid=0 gid=2000
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: nslcd_pam_authc("jorge.suarez","","su","***")
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=jorge.suarez))")
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.54.31/)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,10)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,10)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,10)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("uid=ubuntu,ou=Applications,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es","*****") (uri="ldap://172.16.54.31/")
nslcd: [7b23c6] connected to LDAP server ldap://172.16.54.31/
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.54.31/)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,10)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,10)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,10)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("uid=jorge.suarez,ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es","*****") (uri="ldap://172.16.54.31/")
nslcd: [7b23c6] connected to LDAP server ldap://172.16.54.31/
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="uid=jorge.suarez,ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es", filter="(objectClass=posixAccount)")
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: connection from pid=15906 uid=0 gid=2000
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: nslcd_pam_sess_o("jorge.suarez","uid=jorge.suarez,ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es","su","/dev/pts/7","","jorge.suarez")
```

It seems to me that it won't even try to look for groups. What I am doing wrong? I can't see anything relevant to my problem information on [the docs](http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/docs.html). I'm probably not understanding how the `map` option works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `map group` parameter needs to be associated with a corresponding `filter group` parameter.  Here's how I use it connecting to Active Directory:

```
filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Linux-SA,OU=Groups,DC=global,DC=example,DC=com)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*)(unixHomeDirectory=*)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
map    passwd uid              sAMAccountName
map    passwd homeDirectory    unixHomeDirectory
map    passwd gecos            displayName
map    passwd loginShell       "/bin/bash"
filter shadow (&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*)(unixHomeDirectory=*))
map    shadow uid              sAMAccountName
map    shadow shadowLastChange pwdLastSet
filter group  (&(objectClass=group)(gidNumber=*))
map    group  uniqueMember        member
```